# Use SQL to add rows to a select statement and join data based upon timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm essentially adding an event to a changelog. Presuming I have an initial changelog that looks like this.

changelog table:

| id | timestamp | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 1 | 20 | B |
| 1 | 30 | C |
| 2 | 10 | A |
| 2 | 20 | B |

I also have an event table that looks like this:

| id | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 | alpha |
| 2 | 15 | alpha |

I'm trying to add the rows from the event table to the changelog table so that the end table looks like this

| id | timestamp | state | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A | null |
| 1 | 20 | B | null |
| 1 | 25 | B | alpha |
| 1 | 30 | C | null |
| 2 | 10 | A | null |
| 2 | 15 | A | alpha |
| 2 | 20 | B | null |

The difficulty I'm having is on the row I'm adding in I need to fill the state with the state from the row above or row with the most recent timestamp before the timestamp of the row I'm adding. I can't simply use for example the current state.

Is this possible to achieve using SQL?

At the minute I'm just leaving the state null for the added event which isn't what I want.

```
SELECT 
  *,
  null as event
FROM changelog
UNION
SELECT
  *,
  null as state
FROM event
```

I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: can you explain how do you get the two new output events marked as `alpha` specifically?

Comment: I've edited the post to add the event table explicitly, hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to merge the two tables using a `UNION` statement. Then you can translate the null values (with the `COALESCE` function) in the "state" column with the last "state" value using the `LAG` window function, which will order on the timestamp for each different id.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, timestamp, state, null AS event FROM changelog_
    UNION
    SELECT id, timestamp, null AS state, event FROM events_
)
SELECT id,
       timestamp,
       COALESCE(state, 
                LAG(state) OVER(PARTITION BY id
                                ORDER     BY timestamp)) AS state,
       event
FROM cte
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oHePBggiFiVLfji8ufSfhY/0).

Comment: This works for me, the LAG window function was what I was missing thanks!